# "Select certificate" dialog not showing in android webview

Tags: android, authentication, webview, ssl-certificate, webviewclient

If I try to sign in to web-url via a Chrome / Microsoft Edge browser that has access to certificates on android device then everything works fine.

**Screen shot for the chrome/edge browser working:**

[image: Select Certificate dialog in Chrome/ Microsoft Edge browser]

I try to sign in to web-url on android app using Android web-view but "Select certificate" dialog not showing in android web-view.

I have also come across [`onReceivedClientCertRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedClientCertRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ClientCertRequest)) method which is added in API level 21 but my app required support back to API level 17.

1. Does `onReceivedClientCertRequest` method will handle the "Select
   certificate" dialog automatically ?

I have some common doubts regarding these certificate and "Select certificate" dialog.

1. How to implement such client authentication flow in android mobile
   app using web-view for all Android API levels >= 17.
2. What is the type of available certificates on android devices which used for this type of authentication.
3. How to implement such authentication flow in android mobile app without using webview for all Android API levels >= 17.

Comment: Any luck? Did you find a way to handle such cases?